# How to add a custom shortcut in ckeditor 4.x?

Tags: ckeditor, keyboard-shortcuts

In Ckeditor i want to create custom shortcut key to change the font-type (font should change by pressing shortcut cut key )
 Need your help

Answer (score 1):

for this it need a custom plugin ,i have create  custom plugin  like this
add this code by creating a plugin name(keystorke)and add it into plugin folder

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'keystrokes', {
        init: function( editor ) {
            editor.addCommand( 'h1', {
                exec: function( editor ) {
                    var format = { element: 'h1' };
                    var style = new CKEDITOR.style(format);
                    style.apply(editor.document);
                    var selectedText = editor.getSelection().getNative();
                }
            } );
            editor.addCommand( 'h2', {
                exec: function( editor ) {
                    var format = { element: 'h2' };
                    var style = new CKEDITOR.style(format);
                    style.apply(editor.document);
                }
            } );
            editor.addCommand( 'h3', {
                exec: function( editor ) {
                    var format = { element: 'h3' };
                    var style = new CKEDITOR.style(format);
                    style.apply(editor.document);
                }
            } );
            editor.addCommand( 'h4', {
                exec: function( editor ) {
                    var format = { element: 'h4' };
                    var style = new CKEDITOR.style(format);
                    style.apply(editor.document);
                }
            } );
            editor.addCommand( 'h5', {
                exec: function( editor ) {
                    var format = { element: 'h5' };
                    var style = new CKEDITOR.style(format);
                    style.apply(editor.document);
                }
            } );
            editor.addCommand( 'h6', {
                exec: function( editor ) {
                    var format = { element: 'h6' };
                    var style = new CKEDITOR.style(format);
                    style.apply(editor.document);
                }
            } );
            editor.addCommand( 'p', {
                exec: function( editor ) {
                    var format = { element: 'p' };
                    var style = new CKEDITOR.style(format);
                    style.apply(editor.document);
                }
            } );



            editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.ALT + 49 , 'h1' ); // ALT + 1
            editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.ALT + 50 , 'h2' ); // ALT + 2
            editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.ALT + 51 , 'h3' ); // ALT + 3
            editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.ALT + 52 , 'h4' ); // ALT + 4
            editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.ALT + 53 , 'h5' ); // ALT + 5
            editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.ALT + 54 , 'h6' ); // ALT + 6
            editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.ALT + 55 , 'p' ); // ALT + 7




        }
    });
```

2 now you need to add one line in config.js file like this 
  config.extraPlugins = 'keystrokes';

3 now it will work forsure